# How to remove my post that has an upvoted answer?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete, answered-questions

I can't remove my post in SO because it has the answer.
Is there a way to remove it?

**Why I want remove:**
I want to do things as perfect as possible, but I found out one of my posts was downvoted 1 time, then I decided to find out what's wrong by  posting question in Meta. Instead of having the answer I wanted, I got even more downvotes on my post in SO :).

If I'm not able to edit my post to make it better I think my post shouldn't exist then, as it's bad, isnt't?

It's kind of chicken-and-egg situation.

**Can you please give me one of the choices**:

1. Let me know what is wrong and I improve my post, because down-vote means there's something not good in it.
2. If I can't improve then let me remove it. I don't want to see the post that is treated as bad one

**Please note**, I'm not caring that my post is down voted, but just having a desire to improve my posts.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure which question you're talking about, but as far as I know, you can delete your question as long as it doesn't have an *up-voted* answer. That's an important distinction to explain why you can't delete your question.

Thanks @psubsee2003 for pointing out, "multiple answers without upvotes will also prevent deletion." I forgot about that one.

Stack Exchange, on principle, emphasizes good answers over not-great questions. We'd rather see a really good answer stick around, so we don't give the asker the ability to remove that content directly.

If you could get in trouble for the content you posted, you could try flagging it for moderator review, and you might be disassociated from it. If the answer is significantly subpar and got an undeserved up-vote, it's possible that a moderator will choose to delete the whole thing, as you're requesting.

But typically, unfortunately, there's not much you can do to get the content removed. It's just not really in-line with the philosophy, once there's an answer that the community, through votes, supports.

That leaves the only viable option as being improving the post. If it is seriously off-topic, you could, again, try flagging, as that would then qualify as a subpar answer. But if it's pretty on-topic and you just don't know why people don't like it, you can ask on meta. I know you mentioned it went through meta and got more downvotes, but that can sometimes be an unfortunate side-effect of the system. Generally, if you go into the question with an attitude, as you have here, of "I'd like help, what can I do to improve my question?" the majority of people will support you, and hopefully you'll end up with an upvote-able question.

Ultimately, in most cases, fix it if you can, and if you can't and you honestly don't know why people don't like it, be vulnerable, and post on meta asking what's wrong. Worst case, you learn for next time.

Comment: multiple answers without upvotes will also prevent deletion

Comment: @psubsee2003 Oh right, thanks! I've edited your comment in.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewHaugen for pointing out `upvoted` answer, so I will edit the title of my post.

Comment: @Matthew Haugen I can't put the link of that post in SO, as it will be down voted again :)

Comment: @MatthewHaugen You wrote:
*Ultimately, in most cases, fix it if you can, and if you can't and you honestly don't know why people don't like it, be vulnerable, and post on meta asking what's wrong. Worst case, you learn for next time.*

You know I tried to do it yesterday, but my post got more down votes. This is the reality...

Comment: @Oscar Therein lies the rub--in some unfortunate scenarios, the process of learning and improving quality involves getting a few more downvotes. It's definitely an investment, both in "personal improvement" (you'll learn how to make good posts, and in turn maybe communicate a bit better, for later) and in rep, since hopefully those few downvotes will be outweighed by the upvotes you get for knowing how to make good posts. If that makes any sense.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen I mean, my post in SO was down voted after I post my question here.

Comment: @Oscar Ohh, sorry, my bad. I drew the totally wrong conclusion there. :P. Anyways, yes, that's called the "meta effect," where tons of people see your post because attention is brought to it, and that leads to more votes, for better or worse. It's tough to get around. That's what I was referring to as the investment.

Comment: The user @Tim he's the one who did that down vote and posted the link of the post in Meta to my SO's post so the same purpose.

Comment: @Oscar Ohh, so that is the question we're talking about. Sorry, I must be having an off-night! I'm sure Tim meant well in his interactions with you here on MSE and his comment on that post. In the meantime, I see no problems with the SO post in question, and have consequently voted it up.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen thanks.